# customize background color of selectInput in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

consider the following simple shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(tags$head(includeCSS("www/mycss.css")),
  selectInput("foo", "Choose", width = '20%',
               multiple = F, selected = "red1", 
               choices = list(red = c("red1", "red2"),
                              green = c("green1", "green2")), 
               selectize = F))

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The file `mycss.css` is in a `www` directory and contains the following:

```
#foo optgroup[label = "red"]{
  color: #990000;
}

#foo optgroup[label = "green"]{
  color: #009900;
}
```

I would like to further add css to customize the `selectInput`.
Currently, the background color of an item when hovered over is blue, I would like to pick a custom hover color for each group separately.

[image]

I tried a couple of things like `#foo optgroup[label = "green"]:hover` but failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to change a custom background-color for an item other than default blue right?

Comment: yes exactly, the blue background should be (e.g.) green in the green section and red in the red section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with `selectize = TRUE` and with css attribute selectors:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(tags$head(includeCSS("www/mycss.css")),
            selectInput("foo", "Choose", width = '20%',
                        multiple = F, selected = "red1", 
                        choices = list(red = c("red1", "red2"),
                                       green = c("green1", "green2")), 
                        selectize = T))

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The css file should look like this:

```
div[data-value = 'red1'].active, div[data-value = 'red2'].active{
  background-color:#990000 !important;
  color: white;
}
div[data-value = 'red1'], div[data-value = 'red2']{
  color: #990000;
}

div[data-value = 'green1'].active, div[data-value = 'green2'].active{
  background-color:#009900 !important;
  color: white;
}
div[data-value = 'green1'], div[data-value = 'green2']{
  color: #009900;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Cettt Please see my edit for the situation of `optgroup`. The text color does not work ? Did you try `div[data-value=red1], div[data-value=red2] {color: red  !important}` ?

Comment: @Cettt I have tried now. This works with my proposal.